# why does Inquire pos returns 0 in Fortran 90

Tags: fortran, fortran90, intrinsics

I'm reading a binary file, direct access, in Fortran 90, and i'm trying to find out the pointer position. For that i use:

```
inquire(unitvector, pos=cur_pos)
```

But when i print the `cur_pos` it's always 0, even after i've read a substantial amount of the file. Why is it 0?

To compile i use:

```
$ ifort -warn all -traceback -free util.F fold2Bloch.f90 -o fold2Bloch
```

Comment: `pos=` isn't Fortran 90 - which is part of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable used for the `POS=` specifier is defined only for a file connected with *stream* access, rather than the chosen *direct* access.  `0` is a possible result in this case.

With direct access the position perhaps doesn't really have much general value: the point of such a connection is random access.

From the [draft standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf), section 9.10.2.22 (my emphasis):

> The *scalar-int-variable* in the POS= specifier is assigned the number of the file storage unit immediately following the current position of **a file connected for stream access**. [..] **If** [..] **the file is not connected for stream access** [..] **the variable becomes undefined**

Comment: That sure explains it. Do you know of another way to see how far along the way you are?

Comment: If you're doing direct access then keep count of how many records you've read and find how many you will read in total?

Comment: Hmm, that's an idea. However, when i inquire for record length, using recl, i get 540. I've done a bit of reading and in direct access all record lengths must be the same. Now what does that 540 mean? Bytes, bits?

Comment: It is _probably_ bytes, but it will be `540*FILE_STORAGE_SIZE` bits.  See your compiler's documentation.

Comment: @AntonB For direct access, there is no concept of the current position in the file. You read or write a record as specified by the REC= specifier in the READ/WRITE statement. In practice, all implementations running on Unix/Windows type systems place record #N starting at (N-1)*RECL*FILE_STORAGE_SIZE bits.

Comment: And once again i'm stuck, the math just isn't adding up. Can you guys make a suggestion as to how i should approach my problem. I'm trying to make a progress bar based on percentage of the file read (maybe another way?). These are 100MB and higher binary files.